# SwiftUI Custom TabView Indicator

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabview, indicator

I cannot center the indicator on which the page is located. I cannot ignore the views on the left and right. When the number of page increases, it is inevitable that the indicator of the page I am on will shift to the left when the indicator number on the right is more than the indicator number on the left.
[image]

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    
    var pages: [Page] = [
        Page(page: PageOne()),
        Page(page: PageTwo()),
        Page(page: PageThree()),
    ]
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.init()) {
            TabView {
                ForEach(pages.indices, id: \.self) { item in
                    
                    if item == 0 {
                        AnyView(_fromValue: pages[item].page)
                            .overlay(
                                GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                                    let minX = proxy.frame(in: .global).minX
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        withAnimation(.default) {
                                            self.offset = -minX
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return Color.clear
                                }
                                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                                ,alignment: .leading
                            )
                    } else {
                        AnyView(_fromValue: pages[item].page)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .overlay(
                HStack(spacing: 15) {
                    
                    ForEach(pages.indices, id: \.self) { item in
                        
                        ZStack {
                            Capsule()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: getCurrentPageIndex() == item ? 20 : 7, height: 20)
                                .frame(maxWidth: getCurrentPageIndex() == item ? .infinity : nil, alignment: .center)
                                
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                ,alignment: .bottom
            )
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    
    func getCurrentPageIndex() -> Int {
        let index = Int(round(Double(offset / getScreenWidth())))
        return index
    }
    
    func getOffset() -> CGFloat {
        let progress = offset / getScreenWidth()
        
        return 22 * progress
    }
}

struct OnboardingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OnboardingView()
    }
}

struct Page: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var page: Any
}

extension View {
    func getScreenWidth() -> CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw when you are on the first page, the 2 indicators on the right kind of looks like a pause button. It might look better to make it more near the center.

Comment: You can try to increase the number of pages.  i shared all the codes.
all you have to do is open a new swiftUI file and add it to the pages array.

Comment: Was this issue solved?